# Running Google Maps onMapReady with Services - Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, service

My Google Maps aim is simply search another marker's circles and detect the user is inside of those circles or not. I can do it as visual.

But, I want to implement this to IntentServices, I have a tried but couldn't make it happen, how can I implement this code to services class?

MapsActivity.java

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private Circle circle;
private LatLng latLng = new LatLng(48.016984, 39.040069);
private float zoom;
private LocationListener locationListener;
private ArrayList<SurveyModel> surveyModelList;

//received intent from MainActivity
private double received_latitude;
private double received_longitude;

//user location
private double user_latitude = 48.016803;
private double user_longitude = 39.038556;

//detection calculation
float[] distance = new float[2];

//main activity informer toast
private String informer;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    //add new marker for first survey
    surveyModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    surveyModelList.add(new SurveyModel(0,41.017316,29.038480,135));

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
   /* LatLng sydney = new LatLng(41.016984, 29.040069);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Anket Deneme No: 1"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
            .center(new LatLng(41.016984, 29.040069))
            .radius(400) //400 meters
            .strokeColor(Color.parseColor("#42A5F5"))
            .fillColor(0x60BBDEFB));

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
    */

    //CREATE NEW MARKERS FOR SURVEYS

    for(int j=0;  j<surveyModelList.size(); j++){
        mMap.addMarker(
                new MarkerOptions().position(
                        new LatLng(surveyModelList.get(j).getLatitude(),
                                surveyModelList.get(j).getLongitude())).
                        title(String.valueOf(surveyModelList.get(j).getId())));
        circle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                .center(new LatLng(surveyModelList.get(j).getLatitude(), surveyModelList.get(j).getLongitude()))
                .radius(surveyModelList.get(j).getRange())
                .strokeColor(Color.parseColor("#42A5F5"))
                .fillColor(0x60BBDEFB));
    }

    //users marker
    mMap.addMarker(
            new MarkerOptions().position(
                    new LatLng(user_latitude,
                           user_longitude)).
                    snippet("HERE YOU ARE").
                    title("YOU ARE HERE!"))
    .setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));


    Location.distanceBetween(user_latitude, user_longitude, circle.getCenter().latitude, circle.getCenter().longitude,distance);
    if(distance[0] > circle.getRadius()){
        informer = "Outside";
        Toast.makeText(this, "Outside", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        informer = "Inside";
        Toast.makeText(this, "Inside", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(user_latitude,user_longitude), 14));

}
```

}

.........................................................................

Comment: which code? the whole thing?

Comment: I only need to implement this MapsActivity and run as Service. For example, when user click a button in MainActivity like "See Detections"
I will run this class as service and give user a toast/info like "inside" or "outside" which I decleared in MapsActivity.